# HTTPS site will not load in IE9 and Chrome but will load in Firefox on local network

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, https

Site is https://www.ixl.com/signin

I can load it fine at home in the same browsers but at my workplace it will not load from most of our network except for in Firefox. We do have a web filter solution in place (iPrism) and it is set to block nothing on a specific vlan which my computer is on. From this vlan the site loads fine. To do some testing I set it to not block anything for specific IP addresses on other vlans and still could not get through to the site from those.

An odd thing that made it work in IE 9 is to go to Internet Options, Advanced Settings, uncheck SSL v3, restart IE. Go back and check it again, restart IE. Site loads now. Someone at this thread pointed it out, but the whole thing is essentially no further help: http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/251086-site-will-not-display-in-ie-or-chrome-but-works-in-firefox

Chrome is version 30. FireFox is version 24. Also tried on an up-to-date Chromebook with the same result as Chrome in Windows.

Beyond what I've already tried I don't even know where to begin with this. I would really appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up happening with another web site so I contacted EdgeWave (iPrism) support. The problem was that our web filter was blocking digicert.com (no idea why). This wasn't showing up in the normal block lists so it made it difficult to find as the culprit. After unblocking it in the filter the problem was solved.